# Python Eror unsupported operand types in function

Tags: python

I am trying to write a script to use my sensehat for temperature/pressure/humidity in a room, and when running this script, only my thermometer function returns this error (it runs last)

```
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "room_diagnostics.py", line 33, in <module>
            thermometer()
          File "room_diagnostics.py", line 13, in thermometer
            print(prtemp + "degC")
        TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Full script:

```
#defining libraries
from sense_hat import SenseHat
from time import sleep
sense = SenseHat()
sense.clear()



#defining thermometer function to print
def thermometer():
    temp = sense.get_temperature()
    prtemp = (int(float(str(temp))))
    print(prtemp + "degC")

#defining barometric pressure measurement function to print
def barometric():
    pressure = sense.get_pressure()
    strpressure = (str(int(pressure)))
    print(strpressure + "mbar")


#defining humidity measurement function to print
def humidity():
    humid = sense.get_humidity()
    strhumid = (str(int(humid)))
    print(strhumid + "\% H")

#do it again
while True:
    sleep(1)
    humidity()
    barometric()
    thermometer()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`prtemp` is integer and can't be add to string using `+`

You can convert int to string:

```
print(str(prtemp) + "degC")
```

or, better, use formating:

```
print("{}degC".format(prtemp))
```

or

```
print(f"{prtemp}degC"))
```

Comment: or using f-strings `print(f"{prtemp}degC")`

Comment: thank you! worked perfectly. sorry for the dumb question, im still learning python.